# Plotting function with Dynamic parameter

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I'm trying to get this code working:

```
a = 2;
func[t_] := Dynamic[t + a];
Plot[func[t], {t, -5, 5}]
```

The idea is: I'd like to have the dynamic parameter a change the graph, without the need of actually re-evaluate the `Plot` command after each change of the parameter `a`. But this code delivers no plot printed on the screen. I've tried adding an `Evaluate` command as well, without luck.

What am I missing of the `Dynamic` command? Or where did I do something wrong?

Thank you all for your answers and your help!

Comment: I can read this question a couple of ways.  It is easy to do if `Plot` is to be reevaluated dynamically as the current answers show -- that is, the user does not have to hit shift-enter.  It is possible to do if you do not want the function `Plot` to be actually reevaluated every time the parameter `a` changes, but the result will likely be dissatisfying, unless your example `func` is exactly the function you want to use.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm intrigued by the second possibility you mention. I don't know a lot about the dynamic capabilities of Mathematica, so could you elaborate what you have in mind?

Comment: @sebhofer What I had in mind was taking the `Graphics` output from `Plot` and remapping the coordinates to depend dynamically on `a`.  It seems a bad idea to me.  Since `Plot` makes choices depending on `func`, you lose that.  (The sample function could be done with `Graphics@Dynamic@Line[{{-5, -5+a}, {5, 5+a}}]`, but I assume the OP has something more complicated in mind.)  I haven't been able to imagine a situation in which this second method would be a real advantage.  But technically, it should be *possible.*

Comment: @MichaelE2 Now I see what you... that would of course be closer to the OP's original idea.

Comment: In your comments to answers provided you below keep talking about using locators. You need to put the details of what you want in your question. Readers are not psychic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easier way to do what I mentioned in a comment.  We avoid `Plot` altogether and simply plot a line.   You miss out on the recursive refinement that `Plot` offers to smooth out curves of high curvature, but in some cases that might be ok.  You can even make the pllot depend on the function dynamically.

```
a = 2;
f = func1;
func1[t_] := t + a;
func2[t_] := Sin[a t];
Block[{a, f}, pts = Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, -5, 5, 1/10}]];

Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[
   Dynamic @ pts,
   {Darker @ Blue, Line[Range @ Length @ pts]}],
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change `f`:

```
f = func2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Change `a`

```
a = 20
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here you see the problem.  The function being plotted, `Sin[20 t]`, oscillates too rapidly and you get sharp corners.  (Set it much higher and you will miss entire periods.)

---

If you're interested in simple transformations depending on a parameter, then you can use [Geometric Transforms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GeometricTransforms.html).  The following shows the plot of `t + a`, as sought in the question.

```
a = 2;
plot = Plot[t, {t, -5, 5}];
Dynamic@ReplacePart[plot, 1 -> Translate[plot[[1]], {0, a}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[t+a,{t,-5,5}],{a,0,1}]
```

Now you can vary `a` between 0 and 1. If you want to plot a more complicated function you can do

```
f[a_, t_] := a + t;
Manipulate[Plot[f[a, t], {t, -5, 5}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

Edit

As a response to the OP's comment: `Manipulate` can also be used with a `Locator`, like this

```
Manipulate[Plot[Norm@p2*t + Norm@p1, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}], 
{{p1, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{p2, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, but I'd like to not use Manipulate. I'm searching for a way of having an "invisible Locator" somewhere on the graph which modulus (distance to 0) is a, and to move the Locator and thus changing the value of a. This is, I think, not possible inside Manipulate—but I could be wrong.
Could you help with this too? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @user7285 Then you should state so in your question! But yes, this can be accomplished in `Manipulate`, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `Dynamic` try to make something like this:

```
Dynamic[a];
a = 0;
Slider[Dynamic[a]]
Dynamic[Plot[x + a, {x, 0, 6}]]
```

But, I recommend to use `Manipulate`, `Dynamic` is not a suitable tool for this.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, this helped well. I have now this problem: when using the code here, the two Locators move together. I think, it's due to the Plot command, as the two Locators move independently if I delete that command. Where is the problem?

DynamicModule[{pt1 = {1, 2}, pt2 = {4, 3}},

 Dynamic@Show[
    Plot[x *pt1[[1]], {x, 0, 6}, PlotRange -> 10]
   ,
    Graphics
      [{
        Locator[Dynamic[pt1]]
        , Locator[Dynamic[pt2]]
       }]
    ]
 ]

Comment: This does not seem an unreasonable use of `Dynamic` here.  There are issues with `a` being uninitialized at the beginning of a session.  One could use `Dynamic[If[NumericQ[a], Plot[x + a, {x, 0, 6}], "Initialize a"]]` if for some reason one wants `a` to be a global variable.  (By the way, the first line `Dynamic[a];` is unnecessary.)

Comment: @user7285 The `Locator` question probably ought to be stated as a new question.