# Constrain movement of Locator

Tags: dynamic, locator

Continuing the discussion started in the thread [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29888/constrain-movement-of-a-locator-inside-manipulate), I've tried to recreate the code from scratch. I thus looked to constrain the movement of a locator to the graph defined by

```
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
```

If the locator is at point pt, then

```
Table[{t,Norm[f[t] - pt]}, {t, 0, 2, 0.001}]
```

is a list of couple {t, distances}, which can be sorted with `Sort` and the t-value can be found back using

```
First[First[Sort[Table[
{t, Norm[f[t] - pt]}
, {t, 0, 2, 0.001}], (#1[[2]] < #2[[2]]) &]]]
```

Changing the variable pt by `#` to create a Pure Function used by the second argument of the `Locator` command, I tried the code

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}]
 ,
 Graphics[{
   Locator[ptt,
    ptt =
     (f[First[First[Sort[Table[
            {t, Norm[f[t] - #]}
            , {t, 0, 2, 0.001}], (#1[[2]] < #2[[2]]) &]]]]) &
    ]
   }]
 ]
```

which doesn't work at all. I think there is an error due to expansions of some sorts, but don't know where. Any help with this? The answer found in the link above is working, of course, but I'm trying to find something "shorter", if possible.

All help, as always, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `Dynamic` around `ptt` and the update function.  You also have a misplaced parenthesis in your update function.

```
ptt = {0., 0.};
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
Show[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}], 
 Graphics[{Locator[
    Dynamic[ptt,
           (ptt = f[First[First[Sort[Table[{t, Norm[f[t] - #]}, {t, 0, 2, 0.001}],
                                     (#1[[2]] < #2[[2]]) &]]]]) &]
     ]}
 ]]
```

**Update**

Your approach can be sped up by storing the evaluations of `f[t]` instead of recalculating them each time the `Locator` moves:

```
ptt = {0., 0.};
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
fvalues = f /@ Range[0, 2, 0.001];
Show[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}], 
 Graphics[{Locator[
    Dynamic[ptt, (ptt = First @ SortBy[fvalues, Function[f0, Norm[f0 - #]]]) &]
  ]}]]
```

Even more efficiency can be obtained by using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nearest.html) instead of sorting, as in my answer to the linked question.  You can apply `Nearest` to `fvalues` above or the values already calculated by `ParametricPlot`, which I get below using `Cases`.

```
ptt = {0., 0.};
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
plot = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}];
ptfn = Nearest @ First @ Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
Show[plot, Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[ptt, (ptt = First@ptfn[#]) &]]}]]
```