# Constrain movement of Locator (increased t-value)

Tags: locator

Continuing with the code at the end [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32789/constrain-movement-of-locator), I am now searching for a way of constraining the movement of the locator so that it doesn't "jump" from one "part" of the graph of f to another.

So, if for example the graph of f has an intersection, as in

```
f[t_] := {Cos[5 t], Sin[4 t]}
```

then, I'd like the locator to be constrained for increased values of t, so that it "simply" continues the graph of `f` without "jumping" `t`-values.

Now, I thus tried, instead of using `fvalues` as defined in the earlier link, to use something like this

```
Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 2, 0.1}];
```

and then to sort it accordingly with

```
SortBy[fff, Function[f0, Norm[f0[[2]] - #]]
```

but when I insert this into the second argument of the `Dynamic` of the `Locator`, the constrained movements don't change...

Any help, as always, very much appreciated!

Comment: I think  slider is much more "natural" than a locator for those cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (based on your previous Q&A)

```
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}

v = 3;
ptt = Append[f[#], v #] &[1.0];
plot = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}];
ptfn = Nearest@Table[Append[f[t], v t], {t, 0, 2, 0.01}];
Show[plot, 
 Graphics[{Locator[
    Dynamic[Most[ptt], (ptt = First@ptfn@Append[#, Last[ptt]]) &]]}]]
```

I add `t` as the third element to `ptt`. Here `v` is the adjustable parameter which means the strength of the prevention of jumps.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To get the point to track the angle of the mouse, one can approach the problem in a different way by using `ArcTan` to get the angle and `Mod` to get the angle in the right range.

This below only lets angle increase (by no more than `π`).  Once it gets to the end, the `Locator` will be stuck there.  Reevaluate the code to reset it.

```
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
ptt = {0., 0.};
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}],
 Graphics[{
   Locator[
    Dynamic[ptt,
            (ptt = f[Clip[Mod[If[# == {0., 0.}, 0, ArcTan @@ #], 2 π, 10 Norm@ptt - π]/10,
                          {Norm@ptt, 2}]]) &]]
   }]]
```

This will let the angle increase or decrease (by no more than `π`):

```
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]}
ptt = {0., 0.};
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}],
 Graphics[{
   Locator[
    Dynamic[ptt,
            (ptt = f[Clip[Mod[If[# == {0., 0.}, 0, ArcTan @@ #], 2 π, 10 Norm@ptt - π]/10,
                          {Max[Norm@ptt - π, 0], 2}]]) &]]
  }]]
```

---

*Alternate method*

One can also minimize the distance from the curve to the `Locator`.

```
f[t_] := t {Cos[10 t], Sin[10 t]} + t {Cos[53 t], Sin[53 t]}/2;
t0 = 0;
ptt = f[t0];
Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 2}],
 Graphics[{Locator[
   Dynamic[
    ptt,
    (t0 = Clip[t /. Last @ FindMinimum[#.# &@(# - f[t]), {t, t0}, 
                                       AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3],
               {0, 2}]; 
     ptt = f[t0]) &]
  ]}]]
```

[image: Screenshot of Locator tracking the curve]