# Constrain Locator to specified region

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

How can I constrain the locator to stay within the region defined by `RegionPlot`?

When the `Locator` remains within the region, `NDSolve` generates a periodic solution. (The boundary of the region represents a homoclinic orbit for the DE. When the `Locator` is outside the boundary of the region, `NDSolve` generates an unbounded orbit. Actually, the boundary of the region is the solution to the DE with initial condition $x(0) = -6,\; y(0) = 0$.)

Additionally  a strange behavior occurs whenever the left mouse button is pressed: the right end of the region is truncated. Why?

```
Manipulate[
region = RegionPlot[y^2 < x^2*(1 + x/6), {x, -6, 0}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}];
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t] + x[t]^2/4, 
  x[0] == p[[1]], y[0] == p[[2]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, T}];
psol = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 0}, {-3, 3}}, PlotStyle -> Red ];
Show[{region, psol}], {{p, {-2, 0}}, Locator}, {{T, 5}, 0, 12, 0.1}]
```

I suspect that `Dynamic` needs to be introduced here, but I don't know how to implement it successfully.

Comment: Add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to `RegionPlot` to override the default settings `PerformanceGoal -> ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"]` for plots inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: Have you searched for related questions? [This one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29888/constrain-movement-of-a-locator-inside-manipulate?rq=1) for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- > How can I constrain the `Locator` to stay within the region defined by `RegionPlot`?

  You can check if `Locator's` coordinates fulfill the condition defining your region. It can be done with the second argument of `Dynamic` if you introduce `Locator` explicitly. Take a look at line with `Locator[Dynamic[p, With[{...`
- > A strange behavior occurs whenever the left mouse button is pressed: the right end of the region is truncated. Why?

  The body of a `Manipulate` is effectively wrapped with `Dynamic`. Each time you move something, it will be evaluated. During dynamic evaluation `$PerformanceGoal` is set to `"Speed"` unless you change it. It results in less sampling points and cut corners.

  You can change it to `"Quality"` but here there is no point in evaluating `region` each time anyway. It is independent from `T` and `p` so let's do it outside, once for good.

**Edit:**

- > Your answer is just what I wanted though I need to create a CDF demo. Unfortunately I obtained an error message upon creating a CDF from your answer.

  That's because `region` definition is forgotten as soon as  the *Kernel* is quit, in contrast to `Manipulate`s and `DynamicModule`s variables generated "on fly" like `sol` and `psol` here.

  You can use `SaveDefinitions->True` or inject the `region` with `With`.
- > I also tried to change the appearance of the locator to a disk but was challenged there as well.

  For custom `Locators` it is better to set `Appearance->None` and display whatever you want in its coordinates.

```
With[{
  region = RegionPlot[y^2 < x^2*(1 + x/6), {x, -6, 0}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}]
},

Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[
   {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t] + x[t]^2/4, 
    x[0] == p[[1]], y[0] == p[[2]]}, 
   {x, y}, {t, 0, T}
 ];
 psol = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, T}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-6, 0}, {-3, 3}}, PlotStyle -> Red
 ];

 Show[{
   region, psol, 
   Graphics[{
    Dynamic @ Disk[p, .1],
    Locator[Dynamic[p, 
      With[{x = #[[1]], y = #[[2]]}, If[y^2 < x^2*(1 + x/6), p = #]] &],
      Appearance -> None 
    ]
    }]
   },
   AspectRatio -> Automatic
 ], 
 {{p, {-2, 0}}, None}, {{T, 5}, 0, 12, 0.1}
]]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is just what I wanted though I need to create a CDF demo. Unfortunately I obtained an error message upon creating a CDF from your answer. I also tried to change the appearance of the locator to a disk but was challenged there as well. If these comments go beyond the parameters of my original question, I will resubmit as a new question.

Comment: @Stephen `region` will not be found unless you use `SaveDefinitions ->True` for the `Manipulate`. You can use `Appearance->None` on locator and display a disk separately. Will include those things to my answer later.

Comment: Your comment was all I needed. All works well now: CDF and the appearance of the locator, I appreciate your explanations in your answer that you posted yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of Kuba's answer that uses `RegionNearest[]`:

```
Manipulate[Show[RegionPlot[region], 
                With[{sol = NDSolveValue[{x''[t] == x[t] + x[t]^2/4,
                                          x[0] == p[[1]], x'[0] == p[[2]]}, x,
                                         {t, 0, T}]}, 
                     ParametricPlot[{sol[t], sol'[t]}, {t, 0, T}, 
                                    PlotRange -> {{-6, 0}, {-3, 3}}, PlotStyle -> Red]], 
                     Graphics[{Dynamic[Disk[p, .1]], 
                               Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = rnf[#]) &], Appearance -> None]}], 
                AspectRatio -> Automatic],
           {{p, {-2, 0}}, None}, {{T, 5}, 0, 12, 1/10},
           Initialization :> (region = ImplicitRegion[y^2 < x^2*(1 + x/6),
                                                      {{x, -6, 0}, {y, -2.5, 2.5}}];
                              rnf = RegionNearest[region];)]
```

which should yield the same interface as his answer.