# HighlightGraph without redrawing the underlying graph?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

I have an animation that generates a graph, then highlights different points on it over time. I use `HighlightGraph`. The graph is very big, and this seems to bog down the animation.

I am wondering if there is any way to optimize this, say, by making Mathematica not redraw the underlying graph with `HighlightGraph`?

Comment: Probably not but you can do something like `Show[ graph, Dynamic@highlightedPointsWithTheSameGraphicsSetting]` or even rasterize `graph` before. Something analogous to [114111](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114111/5478)