# Manipulate with arguments points on a circle

Tags: manipulate, dynamic

Start with the following parametric equations of a torus:

```
R = 2; r = 1;
x3[ϕ_, θ_] := (r Cos[ϕ] + R) Cos[θ]
y3[ϕ_, θ_] := (r Cos[ϕ] + R) Sin[θ]
z3[ϕ_, θ_] := r Sin[ϕ]
```

I construct a function `f` whose inputs of interest will be *pairs* `{{s, t}, {u, v}}` of points on the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin in the plane, that is, on `Circle[]`. Like this:

```
f[{{s_, t_}, {u_, v_}}] := 
   Module[
     {θ = ArcTan[s, t], ϕ = ArcTan[u, v]},
     {x3[ϕ, θ], y3[ϕ, θ], z3[ϕ, θ]}
   ]
```

(The values of `f` at such points should turn out to be points on the torus.)

So as to display values of `f` dynamically for such points, I would like to do something like the following, with a pair of controls:

```
Manipulate[
   f[{{s, t}, {u, v}}],
   {s, t} ∈ Circle[], {u, v} ∈ Circle[]
]
```

Of course that's nonsense: the manipulate arguments are not of the correct form for variable specification.

**What's the simplest way to accomplish that *without* faking it by parameterizing the circle** first, as in the following?

```
Manipulate[
   {u, v} = {Cos[ϕ], Sin[ϕ]};
   {s, t} = {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]};
   f[{{s, t}, {u, v}}],
   {θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}
]
```

Could it be done, for example, by using as controls two locators, one for each of the two copies of the circle?

I am aware of [Constrain Locator to specified region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114108/constrain-locator-to-specified-region). However, in that post the variable is in a region, whereas a circle is not a region as I understand the term.

Comment: Under the "Applications" part of the [docs for `Locator[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Locator.html), there is an example showing how to constrain locators to a circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Column[{Row[{Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Circle[], 
      Locator[Dynamic[pt1, (pt1 = Normalize[#]) &]], Text[Round[pt1, .01], {0, 1.5}]}],
   Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[Large], Circle[], 
    Locator[Dynamic[pt2, (pt2 = Normalize[#]) &]], Text[Round[pt2, 0.01], {0, 1.5}]}]}, 
   Spacer[20]], 
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (R + Cos[u]), Sin[t] (R + Cos[u]), Sin[u]}, 
     {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.4], 
     PlotLabel -> Style[Row[{"f[{pt1, pt2}] =", f[{pt1, pt2}]}], 16], 
     ImageSize -> 400], 
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[f[{pt1, pt2}]]}]]}, 
  Dividers -> Center, Alignment -> Center],
 {{pt1, {Cos[0], Sin[0]}}, None}, {{pt2, {Cos[Pi], Sin[Pi]}}, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to kglr's take, here is how one can use `` Experimental`AngularSlider[] `` inside `Manipulate[]`:

```
With[{R = 2, r = 1},
     Manipulate[Show[torus, 
                     Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
                                 Point[{(R + r Cos[ϕ]) Cos[θ],
                                        (R + r Cos[ϕ]) Sin[θ], r Sin[ϕ]}]}]], 
                Row[{Control[{{θ, 0}, Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[θ]] &}],
                     Spacer[20], 
                     Control[{{ϕ, 0}, Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[ϕ]] &}]}], 
                Initialization :> (torus =
                ParametricPlot3D[{(R + Cos[u]) Cos[t], (R + Cos[u]) Sin[t], Sin[u]},
                                 {t, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> None, 
                                 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.4], ImageSize -> 400];), 
                SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

[image: Manipulate for torus]

Comment: Except that it's using an `Experimental` context function, I find this more evocative of what's going on -- about points rotating around each of the two circles.