# How constrain 2d slider in Manipulate to a specified region?

Tags: manipulate, slider

In a `Manipulate`, how can a 2D slider be constrained to a specified region — for example, to the unit disk $|z| \leq 1$in the following example?

```
Manipulate[
   Graphics[{Circle[],
   Line@{{0, 0}, z}, PointSize@Large, Red, Point@z}],
   {{z, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}
]
```

[image: How constrain 2d slider here to unit disk?]

I am aware of how to do this with a `Locator`, as shown, for example, in answers to [Constrain movement of a locator inside Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29888/148).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

Manipulate[Module[{rgn},
  rgn = If[n === Infinity, Disk[],
    Polygon[CirclePoints[n]]];
  z = If[z \[Element] rgn, z, RegionNearest[rgn, z]];
  Graphics[{
    {Opacity[0], EdgeForm[Black],
     rgn},
    Line@{{0, 0}, z},
    PointSize@Large, Red, Point@z}]],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{n, Infinity, CirclePoints}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 8, Infinity},
     ControlType -> SetterBar}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[{{z, {1/2, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Suppose we just do the unit disk, thereby removing the control for the type of region. Then why exactly is the `Control[z, ...]` function explicitly needed, in contrast to the usual form of a `Manipulate` which just uses `{z, ...}` ?

Comment: From the docs for `Manipulate`, "Inside annotations, controls can be specified using Control." and "Possible annotations given in place of controls include expressions with heads String, Style, **Row**, Item, Text, ExpressionCell, TextCell as well as views and layout constructs such as TabView, Grid, and Multicolumn." If you remove the `Row`, the `Manipulate` can be written `Manipulate[ ... , {{n, Infinity, CirclePoints}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 8, Infinity}, ControlType -> SetterBar}, {{z, {1/2, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}]`

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html) to restrict the `Slider2D` thumb to the desired region:

Restrict the thumb to the unit circle:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], Blue, Disk[], 
   Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line@{{0, 0}, z}, 
   PointSize @ Large, Red, Point@z}], 
 {{z, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, TrackingFunction -> ((z = Normalize[#];) &)}]
```

[image]

You can replace `((z = Normalize[#];) &)` with `((z = RegionNearest[Circle[]][#];) &)` to get the same result.

Use

```
TrackingFunction -> ((z = If[Norm@# > 1, Normalize[#], #];) &) 
(*or TrackingFunction -> ((z = RegionNearest[Disk[]][#];) &) *)
```

to restrict the thumb the the unit disk:

[image]

Alternatively, add the thumb region as a second control:

```
regions = Flatten[{RegionBoundary @ #, #} & /@ 
  {Disk[], Rectangle[{-(1/2), -(1/2)}], Triangle[], RegularPolygon[6]}]

icon[size_: 20] := Tooltip[Graphics[{Blue, #}, ImageSize -> 20], #] &;
setters = # -> icon[]@# & /@ regions;

Manipulate[Graphics[{FaceForm[Opacity[.3]], EdgeForm[{Opacity@1, Blue}], Blue, 
   region, 
   Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line@{{0, 0}, z}, 
   PointSize@Large, Red, Point@z}],
 {{region, Circle[]}, setters, SetterBar, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((region = #; z = RegionNearest[#]@z;) &), 
  Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 2}},
 {{z, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((z = RegionNearest[region]@#;) &), 
  ImageSize -> {100, 100}},
 Method -> "ControlAreaDisplayFunction" -> 
   (Row[Column[#, Alignment -> Center] & /@ #[[1]], Spacer[15]] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing the alternatives!